# Access Denied Exception when trying to write text file to C:\ Drive through Code behind

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2012

I need the programming to specifically save the files dynamically created to the C:\ Drive of the client system.

I tried the following code

```
                    context.Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
                    context.Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename= "TextExport");
                    string path=@"C:\TestFolder";
                    Response.TransmitFile(path);
     try
                    {
                        context.Response.End();

                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.GetType(), "ExMessage", "alert('" + ex.ToString() + "')", true);
                    }
                    finally
                    {
                        this.Dispose();
                    }
```

While debugging I received exception stating that access is denied.

What should I do? I specifically want to save to C Drive

Comment: give access to file to user `iis_iusrs` on web server.

Comment: wait... did you say Client System??

Comment: Yes.. Client system.

Comment: You cannot write to the client drive, C: or otherwise.

Comment: You can (naturally) not access the client from the code behind on a webserver.
I think you need to go back to figuring out the requirements for what you really want to do ;o)

Comment: I am sorry but you cannot. It shouldn't be right. Someone saving files on your computer without you knowing. scary.

Comment: Is there a way of making them authorize the site to save data to specific folder?

Answer (score 0):

Please check if you are in **Admin Mode** if you are using visual studio (Admin execution) , if you are using **IIS** check if your application pool can write in your directory ( C:\ ).

[image]

[image]